# Check multiple tables but Show data only from one table at a time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, codeigniter, join

I have the following table structure:

> Table 1:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
1    | 1    | A
1    | 1    | B
2    | 2    | A
1    | 2    | C
2    | 2    | D
```

> Table 2:

```
col4 | col5 | col6
101  | A    | val1
101  | B    | val2
101  | D    | val3
```

> All the records of Table 2 belong to those records in Table 1 whose
>   **col2** contains **2** in its value field.

Using Active Records in Codeigniter, I need to get the following result sets:

1. Get all records which are common in Table 1 and Table 2 for col4 = 101, col1 = 2, col2 = 2
2. Get all records which are present only in Table 1 for col4 = 101, col1 = 2, col2 = 2
3. Get all records which are present only in Table 2 for col4 = 101, col1 = 2, col2 = 2

My code for case 1 is below:

```
$this->db->select('Table1.*, Table2.*');
$this->db->from('Table2');
$this->db->join('Table1', 'Table1.col3=Table2.col5');
$this->db->order_by('Table1.col3');
$this->db->where('Table1.col1', '2');
$this->db->where('Table1.col2', '2');
$this->db->where('Table2.col4', '101');
$res=$this->db->get();
```

My code for case 2 is below:

```
$this->db->select('Table1.*, Table2.*');
$this->db->from('Table2');
$this->db->join('Table1', 'Table1.col3=Table2.col5','right');
$this->db->order_by('Table1.col3');
$this->db->where('Table1.col1', '2');
$this->db->where('Table1.col2', '2');
$this->db->where('Table2.col4', '101');
$this->db->where('Table2.col5 IS NULL');
$res=$this->db->get();
```

My code for case 3 is below:

```
$this->db->select('Table1.*, Table2.*');
$this->db->from('Table2');
$this->db->join('Table1', 'Table1.col3=Table2.col5','left');
$this->db->order_by('Table1.col3');
$this->db->where('Table1.col1', '2');
$this->db->where('Table1.col2', '2');
$this->db->where('Table2.col4', '101');
$this->db->where('Table2.col5 IS NULL');
$res=$this->db->get();
```

But things are not working as expected. If we consider col1 and col2, case 2 and 3 shows no results. If we skip col1 and col 2, still results are not accurate. Please suggest the right codes.

Comment: have a look at this blog which explains exactly how to use joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @Vickel Thanks for the link. Please have a look at my code. I have implemented the same strategy but still things are not working as expected.